# Reverse hexadecimal number using shell scripts

Tags: bash

I am trying to reverse a hexadecimal number in Bash or any other shell.

For example, I want to reverse the hexadecimal number **4BF8E** and the answer should be **71FD2**, i.e bitwise reversal.

Comment: "reverse" is not the correct word (I was assuming you meant the byte order). You mean "invert" or "calculate the bitwise NOT".

Comment: Bitwise not 4BF8E = FD071 not 71FD2 which is the result of bitwise reverse.

Comment: Hi Jonathon, Thanks for quick reply. Here i mean reverse only. The hexadecimal number should be converted to binary and then reverse the binary bits and convert back to hexadecimal gives **71FD2** as the reverse of **4BF8E**

Comment: ...and reversing bits is definitely not the same as negation. Binary `00001011` reversed becomes `11010000` while negated  it's `11110100` - two entirely different operations. Reversing bits is for example useful in the Fast Fourier Transform (although why one would write FFT in bash...?) or decoding arrays of bits serialized into hexadecimal strings in different ordering.

Comment: For visitors who want to calculate the bitwise NOT in Bash, using 0x2C8B as an example: `hex_nr=0x2C8B; hex_len=$(( ${#hex_nr} - 2 )); inverted=$(printf '%X' "$(( ~ hex_nr ))"); trunc_inverted=${inverted: -hex_len}; echo $trunc_inverted`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo 4BF8E | rev | tr '0123456789ABCDEF' '084C2A6E195D3B7F'
```

Explanation:

- rev reverses 4BF8E to E8FB4
- tr  maps each hexadecimal value to it's bit-reversed value

Comment: The only trouble is try with inputs of 0x4BF8E - valid hex but a problem and with 4bf8e so the tr needs to be extended.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following algorithm:

1. Convert hex number to binary equivalent.
2. Perform bitwise NOT.
3. Convert back to hex.

Comment: I thing _bitwise NOT_ didn't work. I need to reverse. Can u please explain.

Answer (score 0):

A python solution, (assuming that you need a byte alignment):

```
def bin(a):
     """ 
     For python 2 this is needed to convert a value to a bitwise string 
     in python 3 there is already a bin built in
     """
     s=''
     t={'0':'0000', '1':'0001', '2':'0010', '3':'0011',
        '4':'0100', '5':'0101', '6':'0110', '7':'0111',
        '8':'1000', '9':'1001', 'a':'1010', 'b':'1011',
        'c':'1100', 'd':'1101', 'e':'1110', 'f':'1111',
        }
     for c in hex(a)[2:]:
         s+=t[c]
     return s

def binrevers(hex):
   IntForm = int(hex, 16)
   BinForm = bin(IntForm)
   rBin = BinForm[::-1]
   Val = int(rBin, 2)
   return "%x" % Val
```

Trying this interactively:

```
>>> binrevers("4BF8E")
'71fd2'
>>>
```

if you need to do this from the shell then it can be expanded to a script by adding to the end of a .py file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    for i in sys.argv[1:]:
       print i, binrevers(i)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, I don't know much about python, but i will try it.:). Is it applicable for any no of digits.

Comment: Two differences to @OgANgA 's solution above 1) It will error on non-valid hex items & 2 it will always byte align rather than nibble.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very efficient and relatively simplistic method I came up with :

```
[g/n/m]awk 'BEGIN { 
     
    ____=index(___="bits::[%.f]"\
              (_="\n")"%s"(_)_,".")

      __=index("_"(_="0|1|"),_)     

 do { gsub(/[^|]+[|]/,"0&1&",_)
      printf(___,__,_) 
    } while(++__<____) }'
```

And it would generate sequentially sorted bit-reflected bit-strings for all 8-bits, with an output like this :

```
bits::[2]
00|10|01|11|

bits::[3]
000|100|010|110|001|101|011|111|…

bits::[4]
0000|1000|0100|1100|0010|1010|0110|1110|0001|1001|0101|1101|0011|1011|0111|1111|

bits::[5]
00000|10000|01000|11000|00100|10100|01100|11100|00…

bits::[6]…
000000|100000|010000|110000|001000|101000|011000|1…

bits::[7]
0000000|1000000|0100000|1100000|0010000|1010000|01…

bits::[8]
00000000|10000000|01000000|11000000|00100000|10100…
```

Just only 7 cycles of the do-while loop, and you'll have all 256-bytes reflected, pre-sorted by its byte-ordinal value.

At bit-level 4, those bit-strings indeed do correspond to a hex equivalent of `084C 2A6E-195D-3B7F`

```
[g/n/m]awk 'mawk2 '

BEGIN { ___=" bits : %2.f | combos :"\ 
            " %8.f | tot-len : %10.f\n"
          _="0|"(____="1")"|"    

           # specify max-bit-level
           # fail safe default to 8
           #
       ____=(____+=int( 24 ))<(__=3)?__*__:____;    
         __=index("_"_,_)
     do {                          
          gsub(/[^|]+[|]/,"0&1&",_) 
          printf(___,__,(_____=\ 
                length(_))/(++__),_____)  
                         
     } while (__<____) }'

 bits :  2 | combos :        4 | tot-len :         12
 bits :  3 | combos :        8 | tot-len :         32
 bits :  4 | combos :       16 | tot-len :         80

 bits :  5 | combos :       32 | tot-len :        192
 bits :  6 | combos :       64 | tot-len :        448
 bits :  7 | combos :      128 | tot-len :       1024
 bits :  8 | combos :      256 | tot-len :       2304

 bits :  9 | combos :      512 | tot-len :       5120
 bits : 10 | combos :     1024 | tot-len :      11264
 bits : 11 | combos :     2048 | tot-len :      24576
 bits : 12 | combos :     4096 | tot-len :      53248
 bits : 13 | combos :     8192 | tot-len :     114688
 bits : 14 | combos :    16384 | tot-len :     245760
 bits : 15 | combos :    32768 | tot-len :     524288
 bits : 16 | combos :    65536 | tot-len :    1114112

 bits : 17 | combos :   131072 | tot-len :    2359296
 bits : 18 | combos :   262144 | tot-len :    4980736
 bits : 19 | combos :   524288 | tot-len :   10485760
 bits : 20 | combos :  1048576 | tot-len :   22020096
 bits : 21 | combos :  2097152 | tot-len :   46137344
 bits : 22 | combos :  4194304 | tot-len :   96468992
 bits : 23 | combos :  8388608 | tot-len :  201326592
 bits : 24 | combos : 16777216 | tot-len :  419430400
```

In terms of speed,

- up to  8-bits /        single-byte : 0.007 secs
- up to 16-bits / every
  2-byte combo : 0.015 secs
- up to 24-bits / every 3-byte combo : 2.297
  secs

If you're feeling adventurous to experiment at higher bit-string combo levels, make sure your system is capable of handling it :

```
 bits : 25 | combos :   33554432 | tot-len :   872415232
 bits : 26 | combos :   67108864 | tot-len :  1811939328
 bits : 27 | combos :  134217728 | tot-len :  3758096384

 bits : 28 | combos :  268435456 | tot-len :  7784628224
 bits : 29 | combos :  536870912 | tot-len : 16106127360
 bits : 30 | combos : 1073741824 | tot-len : 33285996544
 bits : 31 | combos : 2147483648 | tot-len : 68719476736
```

mawk2   354.61s user 44.08s system 88% cpu **7:29.79** total

I didn't dare push it beyond 31-bit combos. That's already some

- 2.14 billion combos of bit-strings,
- bit-reflected
- in sequential order

  - a single-string with a length of 64.00 GB.

Took my computer some 7.5 minutes to finish that task.

Answer (score 0):

I think one method to help visualize what it means by bit-reflected is to see it in a grid of all 256-bytes bit reflected

- `008040C020A060E 0109050D030B070F0  088848C828A868E 8189858D838B878F8`
- `048444C424A464E 4149454D434B474F4  0C8C4CCC2CAC6CE C1C9C5CDC3CBC7CFC`
- `028242C222A262E 2129252D232B272F2  0A8A4ACA2AAA6AE A1A9A5ADA3ABA7AFA`
- `068646C626A666E 6169656D636B676`**`F6`**`0E8E4ECE2EAE6EE E1E9E5EDE3EBE7EFE`

.

- `018141C121A161E 1119151D131B171F1`**`09`**`8949C929A969E 9199959D939B979F9`
- `058545C525A565E 5159555D535B575F5  0D8D4DCD2DAD6DE D1D9D5DDD3DBD7DFD`
- `038343C323A363E 3139353D333B373F3  0B8B4BCB2BAB6BE B1B9B5BDB3BBB7BFB`
- `078747C727A767E 7179757D737B777F7  0F8F4FCF2FAF6FE F1F9F5FDF3FBF7FFF`

The **diagonally**-mirrored byte would be the **bit-inverted** version for each, as illustrated by bolded example of `xF6` and `x09`

another property is that when you cut the reference string in half, and stack them upon each other, they're exactly 1 off, while the diagonal relationship works the same way:

```
084C 2A6E :: 1st 1/2 - evens
195D 3B7F :: 2nd 1/2 -  odds
```

And if you wanna use regex to recreate the reference string entirely from scratch without actually calculating the individual bits, use this at each layer you wanna add 2 more bits...

```
00 & 10 & 01 & 11 &       # without the spaces
```

… which means - if you wanna calculate them instead without having access to native `bitwise XOR` operation, `base-4` helps the most, since only the middle pair `1 | 2` swap while the outer pair `0 | 3` remains.